# Duplicate key in array

Tags: php, arrays, key, duplicates

How can I print a key that exists in an array?
An example of that:

```
$List = array   (
                'F1' => 'Boli',
                'AE' => 'Joo',
                'TR' => 'Yamm',
                'AE' => 'Xss'
                );
```

The key 'AE' is exists in array, how can I check for duplicate key ?

Also, I have a problem with SELECT QUERY,
I want to select from varbinary datafiled column,
But it always returns [][][][][][][][][][] instead of '0xFF3FFF11FFADACXXCFEFE'

Comment: Please open a new question for each question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you type an

```
array('a' => 'val', 
      'a' => 'val2')
```

in the first place?

2nd question: use `bin2hex`: http://php.net/bin2hex

Answer (score 0):

You cant have 2 same keys in a hashmap as the hashmap is using the key to specify the storage position by its key. If you want some more input on hashmaps read here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

If you do this

```
$List = array   (
                'F1' => 'Boli',
                'AE' => 'Joo',
                'TR' => 'Yamm',
                'AE' => 'Xss'
                );
print_r($List);
```

should result:

```
Array ( [F1] => Boli [AE] => Xss [TR] => Yamm )
```

If you want to check if an key exists before you add another key-value-pair use [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists).

**[edit]**

You cant check this declaration for dublicated keys as this is evaluated before you can check it.

Comment: By "not working" I meant that there will never be two key-value-pairs with the same key.. So you cant check for them

Answer (score -1):

[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array